# Output of java task in Ant

Tags: java, ant, task

I have a .java file and am compiling it using javac in ant. The .class file goes to output directory.  A.class when ran, produces a.txt.

How to run the ant ´java´ task and where will the a.txt go, when ran? I mean which directory? Can I specify the direc. where the output files of java task should go?

Comment: What?!! ... try pasting the build.xml I didn't quite catch what you're saying ( maybe it's me ... I better go home )

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this for reference:

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html

It contains an example of using the Java task to run a specific class, e.g:

```
<target name="run">
     <java classname="A">
             <classpath>
               <pathelement location="output"/>
               <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
             </classpath>
     </java>
</target>
```

It really depends on where you are writing the file out to from A.java.  If it is in the current directory, e.g:

```
File f = new File("./test.txt");
f.createNewFile();
```

then it will output the file relative to where you ran the build file from.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Also look into the "dir" attribute on the <java> ant task. If you set fork="true", ant starts a new JVM for the program you're running. You can control its working directory by setting dir="${basedir}/whatever".